# How to have one branch with full history and one branch with squashed history?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-squash

I have are requirement that the *main* branch has only one (potentially big) commit per issue ID. However, to confirm to the [best practice of small commits](https://addshore.com/2022/02/small-commits/), I also need to create and keep(!) multiple small commits per issue ID.

I have already found an OK solution (I think):

1. Create a feature branch *my-feature-branch* from *main*.
2. Make multiple small commits to *my-feature-branch*.
3. In *main*: `git merge --squash my-feature-branch`
4. *main* now has the big commit, automatically with a message referring to the small commits, so you can always "zoom in" to the detailed history if needed.
5. Keep *my-feature-branch* and stop working on it.
6. Create a new feature branch *my-feature-branch-2* etc.

However, it would still be nicer to not need multiple feature branches for this. It would be nice to just have one extra branch, e.g. *main-detailed*. The problem is that whenever I `git merge --squash main-detailed` to *master*, Git tries to merge the full history of *main-detailed*, because it does not know that some of that history had already been merged via previous `merge --squash` commits. Is it still possible somehow to implement the desired workflow?

Comment: `The problem is ....  Git not know that some of that history had already been merged` sqashing the commits changes the history.  So the answer is no, there's no way to have 2 different commit histories also be the same commit history.

Comment: What is you goal to have one big commit if you see value to have small commits on the other hand ?

Comment: @Ôrel: It is a policy I have to adhere to. It has to to with Gerrit code reviews.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that `main` (with the squashed commits) is some sort of "official" view that must not show the details in the history, and that the detailed branch is a "personal" branch that lets you investigate a more useful history for developers.

I suggest that you keep the following history:

```
0--------A-----------D     <-- main
 \        \           \
  a--b--c--o--d--e--f--o   <-- detailed
```

The two branches have a common base `0`. You develop on branch `detailed`. The first feature consist of commits `a`, `b`, `c`. When it is ready, you switch to `main`, then

```
git merge --squash detailed
```

to create commit `A`. Then you switch back to `detailed` and

```
git merge main
```

This does not introduce any new changes, because the tips of the two branches must be equal at this point.
You repeat the procedure for the feature consisting of commits `d`, `e`, `f` to create the squash-merge commit `D`.

The effect of merging `main` into `detailed` is that the squash-merges will not consider the already merged feature commits. When you look at the history of `main`, the detailed commits are invisible, but when you look at the history of `detailed`, you see all commits, including those in `main`.

Comment: It works almost exactly as you describe, with one exception regarding "the squash-merges will not consider the already merged feature commits": The already merged commits and also the merge-main-into-detailed commits appear in the auto-generated suggested commit message. This could become a problem after a couple hundred commits. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that. If you do the squash-merging in a different repository, and if it is under your control, you could `git replace` the parent of the first commit of a feature to point to the last squash-merge. For example, `git replace --graft d A` would pretend that the histories diverged only at `A` and that `d` is the very first feature commit.

Comment: So `git replace` would be run on *detailed* in a copy of the repository? And then the original repository would squash-merge from that copy?

Comment: Not quite. You have to do the squash merge in the same repository where you do the `git replace` and that repository must have access to `detailed`, of course. Either use a separate repository for that, or you can remove the replacement (revert to the original history) with `git replace -d`. I would not leave the fake history where I do my daily work, hence, I suggest to use a different repository.

Comment: I think this answers/solves the question nicely.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein I don’t think the autogenerated squash message is much to be concerned about. “Merge in feature x” might suffice. Maybe with a hand-written body. I don’t think it’s worth messing with git-replace(1).

Comment: @Guildenstern I am worried that at some point after years of commits an extremely large auto-generated suggested commit message will slow down or even crash Git or GUIs that wrap Git (e.g. TortoiseGit). So I do not consider the problem solved.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Then you can make a “squash” manually using `git merge-tree`. To avoid the large generated merge message.

Comment: @Guildenstern: Thanks. I will try that out in a few days (no time now) and reconsider accepting this answer.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is helpful because it also applies to my original approach in case there needs to be another commit on the feature branch after merging to main, and thus another merge commit on main. This would violate the "one commit per issue ID" policy, but may be required in practice.